# Why Activities are designed where it allows to call onDestroy() after onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

One scenario where an activity does not go through its full life cycle is where there is a requirement to make a decision (may be via an if condition inside onCreate()) and kill the activity immediately by calling Finish() inside the onCreate() method itself. onDestroy() is called after onCreate() when this happens.

This clearly is a deviation from Activity lifecycle. My question is

1) Why is such behavior allowed by Android? Any possible reasons for this?

2) Are there any other ways that this kind of decision making functionality be implemented? Are there any built in facilities like say a widget or background method who does this for the programmer?

Comment: "This clearly is a deviation from Activity lifecycle" -- you are certainly welcome to your opinion. You might consider explaining **why** you think that this is a "deviation from Activity lifecycle" and **why** you think that it is so horrible that "such behavior allowed by Android". You should also consider explaining, in detail, what sort of "decision making functionality" you are having problems with, and what a "widget or background method" has anything to do with any of this.

Comment: First, calling `finish()` does not guarantee the `Activity` is going to be destroyed. You're just telling Android "you can kill this activity when you feel like". Second, how is `onDestroy()` after `onCreate()` a deviation from the `Activity` lifecycle? onDestroy is **always** called after `onCreate()`. Do you mean immediately after without the calls to other intermediate methods (e.g. `onResume()`)?

Comment: @CommonsWare as the answer said(by Hari Krishnan) an activity can be created just for the purpose of showing a splash screen and finish() can/should be called for the reasons explained. Is it not a good idea to provide/have a widget/method which will be called appropriately to show a splash screen? I wanted to know if the framework provides facilities for such tasks which requre creation of an activity minus its full life cycle.

Comment: @CommonsWare Activity is not going through the documented life cycle of onCreate() OnStart() onResume() onPause() onStop() and then onDestroy() is bypassed to make it onCreate() and then onDestroy() without other methods. From a programmer's perspective these kinds of exceptional cases always add to complexity of learning something. So, I wanted to know if there was any valid reason behind allowing something like fall to finish() inside onCreate().

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, I meant the call to onDestroy() without other life cycle methods. Feel free to edit the question that made it any unclear.

Answer (score 2):

> Activity is not going through the documented life cycle of onCreate() OnStart() onResume() onPause() onStop() and then onDestroy() is bypassed to make it onCreate() and then onDestroy() without other methods

It is going through the portion of that lifecycle that is appropriate for the situation. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle): "The visible lifetime of an activity happens between the call to onStart() and the call to onStop()". Hence, in situations like this, where the activity is never visible, there is no need to call `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, and `onStop()`.

> From a programmer's perspective these kinds of exceptional cases always add to complexity of learning something

These sorts of complexities are commonplace in software development for pretty much any platform and environment.

> So, I wanted to know if there was any valid reason behind allowing something like fall to finish() inside onCreate().

Nobody but you knows what you would consider to be "any valid reason".

Most likely, this as an optimization path, to save on CPU time, battery, and possibly some memory, by skipping unnecessary work. Please bear in mind that Android was designed around hardware from a decade ago, where mobile CPUs had ~1% of the processing power of today's devices, let alone devices that may arise in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate from one activity to another and you don't need the first activity to be living anymore (like a splash screen), you might be calling the following from somewhere in the first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And if you don't call that `finish` method and allow that splash screen to be in resumed state. What happens when you press the back button from your `SecondActivity`? You will see the splash screen again! Imagine how horrible that would be. The intention of this Android framework is not to make you pass through all the lifecycle methods of an Activity, but to provide you whatever facilities that you need in your app. I think this example can help you understand why such behaviour is not allowed by Android.

Comment: thanks for explaining this scenario. the question is to know the logic behind allowing finish() inside onCreate() which results in no calls to onStart() and other methods but a call to just onDestroy(). a call from finish() from any method like onStart() or onResume() would have also had the same effect of not showing the splash screen when back button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

As understood from other answers for this question, activities are designed in such a way that they need not go through or invoke all the methods in its life cycle.

Common situations where programmers design activities that do not pass though its full life cycle are like, requirement to display a splash screen. Another requirement is for any any task that does not require a UI at all, and finish() is invoked inside the onCreate() method itself. In this case, as the question suggests, onDestroy() is called immediately after onCreate() without invoking other intermediate methods of activity life cycle.

However, I am not sure about android providing any widgets for any such specific tasks, but it always makes sense to perform any such non-UI tasks in a service rather than an activity whenever possible. It is up to the programmer to decide what is apt for a given requirement.